# How to have multiple authenticator in Symfony2 Security simple_preauth firewall

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, firewall

We are building a Symfony website where it will expose REST API for mobile app but with authentication token, which will autorize the Developer to consume the API, For this feature, I am using `simple_preauth` firewall authenticator, which works just fine. Firewall configuration :

```
firewalls:
    app_authenticated:
        pattern: ^/api
        context: app
        stateless: true
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: api_key_authenticator
```

But our mobile app will offer end-user to login and we need the user's session to be stateless, which means, logged-in user's token has to be supplied along with developer's token, **How do I implement multimple authenticator under simple_preauth firewall index?**

I tried supplying `[api_key_authenticator, api_key_authenticator2]` as 2 authenticators but simple_preauth.authenticator requires value to be scalar, not array. Any help around ?

Comment: Why can't your authenticator handle both developer and user tokens?

Comment: It seems `authenticateToken` method in my ApiKeyAuthenticator gets called only once as configured in firewalls and returns a `PreAuthenticatedToken` instance. Hence I can't validate another key in there.

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible since Symfony 2.8 using Guard authentication:

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/guard_authentication.html

```
    firewalls:
    other_user_access:
        pattern: ^/api/user/email$
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - dev_authenticator
                - api_prod_user_authenticator
                - api_token_authenticator
        entry_point: dev_authenticator
```